# PHP mail form: user inserts his email -> email address should be the sender for easy reply

Tags: php, html, forms, email

what do I need to change in the following code that the user enters his email address in the form. In the mail I receive, the user's email should automatically be the sender - so that I can easily reply. 
Thanks and regards

```html
<?php

 

$zieladresse = 'IhrName@EXAMPLE.com';

$absenderadresse = 'ihrAndererName@EXAMPLE.com';

// Welcher Absendername soll verwendet werden?
$absendername = 'Formmailer';


$betreff = 'Feedback';


$urlDankeSeite = 'http://www.EXAMPLE.com/IhrName/IhreSeite.htm';


$trenner = ":\t"; // Doppelpunkt + Tabulator


require_once "Swift-4.0.7/lib/swift_required.php"; // Swift initialisieren

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "POST") {

    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance(); // Ein Objekt für die Mailnachricht.

    $message
        ->setFrom(array($absenderadresse => $absendername))
        ->setTo(array($zieladresse)) // alternativ existiert setCc() und setBcc()
        ->setSubject($betreff);

    $mailtext = "";

    foreach ($_POST as $name => $wert) {
        if (is_array($wert)) {
                foreach ($wert as $einzelwert) {
                $mailtext .= $name.$trenner.$einzelwert."\n";
            }
        } else {
            $mailtext .= $name.$trenner.$wert."\n";
        }
    }

    $message->setBody($mailtext, 'text/plain');

    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance(Swift_MailTransport::newInstance());
    $result = $mailer->send($message);

    if ($result == 0) {
        die("Mail konnte nicht versandt werden.");
    }

    header("Location: $urlDankeSeite");
    exit;
}

header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de">
    <head>
        <title>Einfacher PHP-Formmailer</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Beispielformular</h1>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <!-- Hier die eigentlichen Formularfelder eintragen. Die folgenden sind Beispielangaben. -->
            <dl>
                <dt>Ihr Name:</dt>
                <dd><input type="text" name="Versender" /></dd>
                <dt>Ihre E-Mail:</dt>
                <dd><input type="text" name="E-Mail" /></dd>
                <dt>Sie können:</dt>
                <dd><input type="checkbox" name="kannwas[]" value="HTML" />HTML <input type="checkbox" name="kannwas[]" value="PHP" />PHP</dd>
                <dt>Sie sind:</dt>
                <dd><input type="radio" name="sexus" value="M" />Mann <input type="radio" name="sexus" value="Frau" />Frau</dd>
                <dt>Sie mögen:</dt>
                <dd><select name="Browser"><option value="Opera">Opera</option><option value="Mozilla">Mozilla</option></select></dd>
                <dt>Bemerkungen:</dt>
                <dd><textarea name="Bemerkungen" rows="3" cols="20">Bemerkungen</textarea></dd>
            </dl>
            <!-- Ende der Beispielangaben -->
            <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Senden" />
            <input type="reset" value="Zurücksetzen" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

What about the following code, it also works, seems not too complicated. What is to be adapted here so that the sender's email is automatically displayed in email program as the sender to uickly reply?

html/php:

```
<form method="post" action="Untitled-6.php">

        <label>Name*</label>
        <input name="name" placeholder="Type Here">

        <label>Email*</label>
        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Type Here">

        <label>Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>

        <label>*What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label>
        <input name="human" placeholder="Type Here">

        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
```

php:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: TangledDemo'; 
$to = 'ceyca82@gmail.com'; 
$subject = 'Hello';
$human = $_POST['human'];

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '4') {                 
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
} 
} else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
}
```

?>

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: You should use `$_POST["Versender"]` to get the field value. And similary for the others.

Comment: I admit it's a bit messy...

Comment: BTW: Why to make a code snipet with php?

Comment: sorry, but the code include function did not work with this (always got an error message)...and you mean include $_POST["Versender"] in the line ...foreach...? that did not work unfortunately......please see also my new edit in the initial question (new code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$absenderadresse = $_POST["E-Mail"];

But there's several problems here:

1) You shouldn't post this kind of questions in stack overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

2) It's plenty of form processing tutorials out there. (Read at least one)

3) That var... "E-Mail"... You should consider calling it "email" (by convention)

Comment: but let me also comment on your side blows. Is stackoverflow only a platform for nerds, wise guys and experts? I guess no. So why shouldn't I post a question like this? And don't you think I checked here, google and read through dozens of pages? I find it rather presumptuous that experts here constantly admit so in advance. There are indeed things that need expert advice I only get here - even if it's a hilarious thing in you eyes...

Comment: I recommend using other forums for these kind of questions. And excuse me for my manners if you felt it rough.

Comment: Just think about it. How can someone who is not an expert really judge upfront if a question is simple and hilarious. Then getting comments like this is simply hilarious (also the hint to use "another forum). You could have also ignored it (which you have thankfully not).